# Как правильно написать метод который будет считать свободные участки(см пример)?

Tags: java

В общем нужно написать такой метод

```
public static int waterVolume (int [] heights)
```

он принимает вот такой массив

```
int[] array1 = {2,1,1,4,1,1,2,3};
```

и должен посчитать вот такое

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть в конкретном случае метод `waterVolume()` должен вернуть `7`

Не получается у меня предствить пока как этот метод должен работать.

Я думал о том, чтоб сделать цикл который будет брать первое значение сравнивать его со следующим и ели оно меньше то разница между величинами прибавляется и так дальше, если следующий столбец выше то он берется как за вершину и следующее значение если меньше то опять разница прибавляется в результат...

Но тогда все равно не получается потому, что (по примеру) если брать столбец по индексу 3 его высота 4 а следующий элемент по индексу 4 у него высота 1, разница получается 4 - 1 = 3... Но на самом деле результат 2 так как крайний элемен имеет высоту 3...

В общем не пойму как это правильно посчитать

Comment: Был этот же вопрос только с меткой JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не помогу вам с конкретным кодом, но алгоритм напишу.

1. Создаёте двумерный массив V[x, y]. x - аналогичен длине входного массива, y - максимальное значение во входном массиве I[x].
2. Заполняете V[x,y] массив как у вас рисунке неким значением (ну типа занято).
3. Пробегаете массив V[x,y] по y. Внутри пробегаете по x.
4. Если клетка занята, то считаете кол-во пустых клеток за ней. Если попалась опять не пустая клетка добавляете полученное кол-во пустых клеток к итоговому значению. Если до конца x не попалась не пустая клетка, то ничего не добавляете.

Алгоритм, что называется "в лоб"

Comment: Да я понял, как это должно быть. Опубликовал решение

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо @ArchDemon

В итоге решение получилось таким

```
/**
 * Calculate water volume according to input data
 *
 * @param input - one dimensional array where a length is width and value is height of the column
 */
public static int waterVolume(final int[] input)
{
    int width = input.length;
    int height = findMaxIn(input);
    int[][] form = new int[width][height];
    fillForm(form, input);

    return calculateWaterVolumeIn(form);
}

/**
 * Calculate water volume according to the form. 
 * 
 * @param form - two dimensional array where length of the array is a width of the form and length of the second 
 *             dimensional array is a height of the form   
 * */
private static int calculateWaterVolumeIn(final int[][] form)
{
    int result = 0;
    final int FULL = 1;

    int tmpVol = 0;
    boolean startCount = false;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < form[0].length ; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0 ; j < form.length ; j++)
        {
            int cellInForm = form[j][i];

            if (cellInForm == FULL)
            {
                startCount = true;

                if (tmpVol > 0)
                {
                    result += tmpVol;
                    tmpVol = 0;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (startCount)
                {
                    tmpVol++;
                }
            }
        }

        startCount = false;
    }

    return result;
}

/**
 * Method fill the form with the input data.
 * 
 * @param form - two dimensional array - actually it is the empty form
 * @param input - one dimensional array - data to fill the form 
 * */
private static void fillForm(final int[][] form, final int[] input)
{
    for (int i = 0 ; i < form.length ; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0 ; j < input[i] ; j++)
        {
            form[i][j] = 1;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Method find the max value in one dimensional array
 * 
 * @param input - one dimensional array
 * */
private static int findMaxIn(final int[] input)
{
    int result = input[0];

    for (int i = 1 ; i < input.length ; i++)
    {
        if (result < input[i])
        {
            result = input[i];
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```